# SecurityError:Blocked a frame with origin Cross Origin Request accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, window.open, rackspace

I have some function in my `javascript(somefunction())` included on my website.

I have static website hosted on rackspace cloud server.

Opening the cloud website from my website(window.open). and calling the function using `window.parent.somefunction()`.

Getting cross origin error because its url is different. I have no control on the website i deployed on the server as it is pre built package. So, i cannot use `window.postmessage()` for it. I need to give the package access to call its predefined functions on my website.

Comment: You can't. You just said you have no control over it.

Comment: @Quentin I have control on rackspace server, but not the files i am deploying to the cloud. It is a pre build that client will upload from his website to cloud(rackspace).

Comment: Have you investigated what cross-origin errors are exactly, and how they may be solved? You're already using the right keyword, so I assume you've done *something* already to approach a solution? Did something specifically work or not work?

Comment: @deceze I know about cors, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS. Problem is that i can't use parent javascript object due to it. I am using Scorm API for educational purposes, that i can't edit its source files that's the problem.